# Eclipse CDT cleans dependent project on cleaning the selected one

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I have two projects, one depends on the other, and when I ask Eclipse to clean the dependent project, it cleans both of them. Is there a way to disable this behavior?

It is worth noting that on building the dependent project eclipse also builds both of them.

I have tried already:

1. Clean up Eclipse Build Order
2. Remove the dependency in Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> References